# How to reset input value in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I want to reset the search text field after i hit enter,close or 'x' button.As per my code it clears the characters after closing the window but when i open it again it doesn't display list of user names until i hit backspace on search field. Any solutions

code:

```
export class child extends parent {
        private findSubject = new Subject();
        constructor() {
            this.init();
            this.findtream = this.findSubject.debounceTime(300);
        }
    }


<button type="button" (click)="close();findName.value=''" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 18px;" [style.left.px]="functionalityActive === 0 ? 723 : 668"><span aria-hidden="true " style="font-size: 37px;">x</span></button>
<input type="text" #findName  class="search-text" (keyup)="findSubject.next(findName.value)">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger event-buttons" id="create-button"(click)="close();findName.value=''">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try for `window.onload()` combining with `getElementById` to set its value when window reloads